# Efficient filtering of list

Tags: java, list, dictionary, guava, list-comprehension

I have a `List<A>`. Lets call it `newList`. Now the class `A` has 2 properties `id` and `weight`. Now the `newList` contains various entries of type `A`. What I want is a Map containing the `id->weight` such that the heaviest(by heaviest I mean the one having the highest value of weight) instance for a particular `id` is mapped.

```
Example say the List contains the following objects:
obj1: id=1 weight=5
obj2: id=1 weight=10
obj3: id=1 weight=12
obj4: id=2 weight=6
obj5: id=2 weight=7
```

The map should be

```
id:1->weight:12
id:2->weight:7
```

What I am currently doing is iterating the list one by one and checking for a given key(id) what is the already existing value(weight) and overwriting if my current value is greater. Although this is fine. I am thinking there might be some more elegant List comprehension I can try with Guava. Any help?

Comment: Can you use Java 8?  It might be a little harder with Guava.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution I could think of using Guava:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> finalMap=Maps.newHashMap();
Multimap<Integer,A> newMap=Multimaps.index(newList, new Function<A,Integer>(){
            public Integer apply(A input) {
                return input.getId();
            }
        });
for(Integer i:newMap.keySet()){
            List<Integer> z=FluentIterable.from(newMap.get(i))
                            .transform(new Function<A,Integer>(){
                                public Integer apply(A input) {
                                    return input.getWeight();
                                }
                            }).toList();
            finalMap.put(i, Collections.max(z));
        }
```

Comparing it to vanilla Java 6

```
Map<Integer,Integer> finalMap=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for(A a:newList){
    if(finalMap.get(a.getId())!=null){
    finalMap.put(a.getId(),finalMap.get(a.getId())>a.getWeight()?finalMap.get(a.getId()):a.getWeight());
    }
    finalMap.put(a.getId(), a.getWeight());
}
```

This seems to be the case of

> Excessive use of Guava's functional programming idioms can lead to
>   verbose, confusing, unreadable, and inefficient code. These are by far
>   the most easily (and most commonly) abused parts of Guava, and when
>   you go to preposterous lengths to make your code "a one-liner," the
>   Guava team weeps

If anyone can pose a solution in Java 8 it would help.

Answer (score -2):

Hi you use FilterCriteria to achieve this task.

Please refer to the [link](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072996/design-patterns/filter-collections.html) for some examples.

Comment: This link points to an article from 2004 (!) with no generics and no common libraries...